# How to remove "W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times..." in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

I had to do an update at a dodgy motel recently. I experienced a power failure during the update. Since then when I try to update I get the following output.

```
chh2@chh2-cpu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for chh2: 
Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                
Hit:4 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease                                 
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                   
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                  
Reading package lists... Done                      
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_NZ) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_NZ) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
```

vi /etc/apt/sources.list and line 54

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list and line 3

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error messages tell you the locations where the changes/corrections need to be made. Personally I'd recommend checking whether or not a source is already added, before adding it a second time to get this error...

Comment: I followed the link you provided and was able to delete duplicate entries in "Software & Update >> Other software". This fixed the issue. Thanks guiverc.